# How to use sqlalchemy expression in read_sql_table using Dask?

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, dask

I am using `df = dd.read_sql_table('mytable_name', 'connection_string',npartitions=10, index_col='id')` to create a Dask dataframe and it is working perfectly. But it is taking all rows of the table. I want to limit the number of rows or apply some conditions. For that, according to the official documentation [read_sql_table](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table) we can use sqlalchemy expression. I am trying to write sqlalchemy expression but none of the way worked for me.

I tried like this:

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

metadata = MetaData()

t = Table('mytable_name', metadata,
Column('id'),
schema='my_schema')
s = select([t]).limit(500)
dd.read_sql_table(s, connection_string, index_col='id')
```

but this is also not working. This is the sqlalchemy expression I found in the Official documentation of sqlalchemy.

Help me with the way of passing sqlalchemy expression in `read_sql_table` using Dask.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "expression" is somewhat overloaded here. You are using the ORM representation, but Dask requires the lower-level SQL function expression syntax. In your case, I believe it would look like

```
from sqlalchemy import sql
expr = sql.select([sql.column("id")]).select_from(
        sql.table("mytable_name")
    ).limit(500)
```

I do not know how to get the schema into there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying that and I am getting this.`expr = sql.select([sql.column("id")]).select_from(
        sql.table('schema_name.table_name')
    ).limit(500)

    df = dd.read_sql_table(expr, uri=connection_string,index_col='id')
    print(df)` Here I am getting `KeyError: 'id'`. and it is compulsory to provide key

Comment: and it is treating it like `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT TOP 5 id 
FROM (SELECT TOP 500 id 
FROM [schema_name.table_name])` @mdurant

Comment: You should use the same variable `sql.column("id")` for the index to in this case.